# displaying german characters in iphone

Tags: iphone, character-encoding

i have following string coming in the json response. 
"Gas-Heizung-Sanit\u00e4r" so how to display it. i want to display that \u00e4 as a german character..

```
NSString *str = "Gas-Heizung-Sanit\u00e4r";
NSLog(@"%c",str);
```

it only prints the german character.

Comment: hey! which encoding are you use? i get the &a as ä. and i am unable to decoding the &a to ä. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following works

```
  NSString *str = @"Gas-Heizung-Sanit\u00e4r";
  NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

You forgot the @ on the string and also the %c is for a character, you should use the %@ for a string